# Searching a tree in c++(not binary)

Tags: c++, search, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I asked a similar question before, but now I'm looking for a why this isn't working instead of "help me fix".

I have to create a general tree that looks like this:

```
                       1
                       /
                      v
                      2->3->4
                     /      /  
                    v       v
                    5-6-7   8-9
```

My search method, which I use for every other method in the class, is

```
gennode* general::search(int element, gennode *t){
  if(t == NULL)
  {
   return t;
  }
  if(t->item == element)
  {
  return t;
  }
  if(t->siblingList != NULL)
  {
  return search(element, t->siblingList)
  }
  return search(element, t->firstChild)
}
```

Where firstChild is the vertical pointers in the picture and siblingList is the horizontal pointers in the picture.

My issue is that it is not finding 5, 6, or 7(the children of 2).

The recursive stack looks like this(at least I think it should in my head):

```
search(5, *1)
search(5, *2)
search(5, *3)
search(5, *4)
search(5, *8)
search(5, *9)
return NULL(from *9)
return NULL(from *8)
return NULL(from *3)
search(5, *5)
return(*5) the rest of the way up.
```

Does anyone know where I am getting lost?

Comment: just a guess, i think you should have `else if`s instead of just `if`s.

Comment: By the way, it is a binary tree (2 childs from each node) but it's not an `ordered` binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to control NULL result in the sibling search:

```
gennode* general::search(int element, gennode *t){
  if(t == NULL)
  {
    return t;
  }
  if(t->item == element)
  {
    return t;
  }
  gennode* result = NULL;
  if(t->siblingList != NULL)
  {
    result = search(element, t->siblingList)
  }
  if(result==NULL)
  {
    result = search(element, t->firstChild);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not what to search first. Is that, on fail, the other way must be attempted. You solved because you did not return on fail!

Comment: This seems like it should be in the right directions, but I got a seg fault when I was searching for 2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
  if(t->siblingList != NULL)
  {
  return search(element, t->siblingList)
  }
```

The return statement makes the function return in any case if there are siblings, independently if something was found or not.

On node 2, you will return having it 3 as a sibling, and the "child" descendance will never be attempted.

This way should be correct

```
gennode* general::search(int element, gennode *t)
{
  if(t == NULL) //no search at all
  { return NULL; }
  if(t->item == element) // found
  { return t; }
  gennode* z = search(element, t->siblingList);
  if(z) return z; // if found return, otherwise ....
  return search(element, t->firstChild); //... try the other way round
}
```

Comment: you don't have to check `t->siblingList != NULL` because the function will take care of it.

Comment: @Roee Gavirel ... Also firstChild ... FIXED

Answer (score 1):

your problem was here, it t->siblingList != NULL you never got to t->FirstChild.

```
gennode* general::search(int element, gennode *t){
    if(t == NULL)
    {
        return t;
    }
    if(t->item == element)
    {
        return t;
    }
    gennode* sibValue = search(element, t->siblingList);
    if(sibValue != NULL)
    {
        return sibValue;// <-- only return if you have a valid value.
    }
    return search(element, t->firstChild)
}
```